# Majesty northern expansion on Android. How can I win that level?

Tags: android, majesty-northern-exp

I tried the map dwarves amusement several times already and can't seem to find a strategy that might work. The previous maps all were OK. This one is weird because I lost even faster on easy setting compared to medium (peacekeeper).

Any hint how to approach this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't go after the monster lairs instead protect them. you just need to destroy the dwarves place and you'll win the level. when all of the monster lairs are destroyed you lose so its the best to protect one of them by using magic (strengthen the monsters,healing etc). the dwarves come in a quantity so make better warriors, paladins etc

Comment: I now won - don't know how. I think I lost before not because the lairs were gone, but because the dwarves killed a building in my city. This I prevented instead and killed all dwarves and I won. Can't confirm that the lairs were not important though. I'll mark the answer as correct because it sounds logical, but I couldn't really confirm it.